# how to fill objects in angular2

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have created this class which in turn has more classes, I would like to know how to fill "OptionsAutocomplete" object with all its objects in angular2. Please help.

```
interface IOpcionesAutocomplete {
    opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;  
    pcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;
}


export class OpcionesAutocomplete implements IOpcionesAutocomplete {      
     opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;
     opcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;
    constructor()  { }
}



interface IOpcionStyle {
    width: number;
    height: number; 
    isOverflowY: boolean;
}

export class OpcionStyle implements IOpcionStyle {
      width: number;
      height: number; 
      isOverflowY: boolean;
    constructor()  { }
}

interface IOpcionPropiedades {
    propiedad1: string;
    propiedad2: string; 
    textoEtiqueta: string;
}

export class OpcionPropiedades implements IOpcionPropiedades {
    propiedad1: string;
    propiedad2: string; 
    textoEtiqueta: string;
    constructor()  { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change some code. add constructor to all your classes with the same manner.

```
export class OpcionesAutocomplete implements IOpcionesAutocomplete {      
     opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;
     opcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;
    constructor(opcionesStyle:OpcionStyle, opcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades )  {
       this.opcionesStyle = opcionesStyle;
       this.opcionPropiedades = opcionPropiedades;
 }
}
```

and then use

new OpcionesAutocomplete(new OpcionStyle(), new OpcionPropiedades())

Comment: in another component I put the following and gives error: 
 import { OpcionesAutocomplete } from './../../shared/forms/autocomplete/opcionesautocomplete.model';
    opcionesAutocompleteClientes : OpcionesAutocomplete = new OpcionesAutocomplete(new OpcionStyle(), new OpcionPropiedades());
 
 
 "Cannont find name OpcionStyle", "Cannont find name OpcionPropiedades" ...

Comment: You need to import them also

Comment: : import { OpcionesAutocomplete, OpcionStyle, IOpcionPropiedades   } from './../../shared/forms/autocomplete/opcionesautocomplete.mode‌​l'

Comment: Thanks, the declaration with the imports works, but when I try to fill an object I get error, this is how I try to fill it:
        
  opcionesAutocompleteClientes : OpcionesAutocomplete = new OpcionesAutocomplete(new OpcionStyle(), new OpcionPropiedades());
  this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.OpcionStyle.width=550;
  this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.OpcionStyle.height=150;
  this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.OpcionStyle.isOverflowY=true;
  
The Error: "OpcionStyle does not exist on type 'OpcionesAutocomplete'"

Comment: You can't do like that. You should add constructor to all classes same way different parameters and pass value to this objects